# Can I delete geometry by rendering?

Tags: rendering

I know it could be weird, but can I for example take all the objects in the scene (static objects) and then render them with low polygons? like transforming them or something like that?

Comment: Try the decimate modifier

Comment: Where's that option?

Comment: Modifiers panel

Comment: remesh modifier can help too, depending on what you need.

Comment: @someonewithpc, going to post an answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the *Decimate* modifier.

Select your object, and in the Properties panel, click the *Modifiers* tab; there, click *Add Modifier* and select *Decimate*. There are a few modes to select from, which give you a slightly different result, but you'll probably want to use *Collapse*. This mode as a *Ratio* slide, which you can use to control how much to decimate your object.

[image: Decimate Modifier]